# Active Record: Showing the first object in a series of objects (optimization)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My app shows event suggestions to users. One issue that has come up is that sometimes there are multiple events, with different dates, in a series, e.g:

- Stanley Theater Presents 'Foo Bar' Night 1
- Stanley Theater Presents 'Foo Bar' Night 2
- Stanley Theater Presents 'Foo Bar' Night 3

What I would like to do is show the user *only* one event in a series with the nearest future start date.

I could write a method that checks if an event is the first in a series:

```
def first_in_series?
  ## return true unless self.siblings.count > 0 && 
    self.siblings.where(:date => Date.today..self.date).first.present?
end

def siblings
  ## some method to get events based on the similarity of their titles and attributes
end
```

Then in my events index, I could write something like:

```
<% future_events.all.each do |e| %>
  <% next unless event.first_in_series? %>
  <%= event.title %>
<% end %>
```

But this seems like it would be taxing when I'm rendering all my events. How can I optimize this query using Active Record Scopes?

Comment: I can not grasp the problem here

Comment: what is `next` for when you will have always one `first_in_series` (btw, method should not have `?`) since it's not boolean it returns

Comment: @AndreyDeineko made some edits. There will not always be one in 'first_in_series'. When self.siblings.where(:date => Date.today..self.date).first.present?  returns false... It means the event has a sibling that has a date before its own date

Comment: @AndreyDeineko But my problem is that this seems inefficient querying the DB in my events loop.  I'd rather scope it out using AR query but can't figure it out.

Comment: It's fairly simple, I just have an Event model and an event has a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think scope might solve it for you:

```
class Event
  has_one :first_sibling, lambda {
    joins(:siblings).where('siblings.date >= ?', Date.today).first
  }
end
```

Then, if I'm not mistaken, the following should work:

```
<%- future_events.joins(:first_sibling).each do |event| %>
  <%= event.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey @AndreyDeineko - thanks for the answer. The issue is I don't have a "siblings" model. I can only identify if events are siblings via a custom method to compare title and venue

Comment: Sorry - my wording of 'sibling' was confusing

Comment: @JacksonCunningham show the siblings method then :)

Comment: @JacksonCunningham the idea is to put this into database query instead of method, then you are guaranteed with speed and efficiency

Comment: Ah okay. I think I understand. So I could create a self-referential has_many association (siblings) for events. Then store in the through table the two event_ids

Comment: correct. give it a try, it might work well. Any db processing is super-super more efficient, than method :)